# Attempting to add shapes to geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to create a geom_point with shapes, I can adjust to data point size and colors but when I enter aes(shape = Messi[4]) I get the error message:

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.

```
Messi[1:4]
   X  Y   xG Result
1  7 46 0.11      1
2  7 43 0.15      1
3 10 51 0.15      2
4 13 45 0.08      2
5  6 35 0.05      2
6 10 52 0.11      3
7  4 50 0.25      3
8 11 57 0.08      3
9  9 34 0.04      3

ggplot(Messi, aes(Messi[1], Messi[2])) +
   geom_point(aes(colour = Messi[3], size = Messi[3]))
```

Comment: You have to make it a factor, so it has a finite number of possible values: `ggplot(Messi, aes(x = X, y = Y, colour = xG, size = xG, shape = factor(Result))) + geom_point()`

Comment: @alistaire - thank you for your help - I attempted that and it returned: "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?

Comment: This will create a plot----      > ggplot(Messi, aes(Messi[1], Messi[2], colour = Messi[3], size = Messi[3])) + geom_point()      -----but I'm still unable to change the shape

Comment: THANK YOU! It took Messi$Result to create the shape!!

Comment: Pleas stop subsetting inside of ggplot. Just use the variable names.

Comment: Can you tell I'm new to this? Using your suggestion, saves me some time! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would not call that an error message, I would call that a notice.

Here is what is happening using the iris data set.

This `iris[1]`  is not the same as `iris[,1]`  or `iris$Sepal.Length`. 
If you run class on each of those you will see that they are different and that `iris[1]` is a data.frame.   ggplot2 is not expecting a data frame.

Also, you need to make your shape variable not be continuous, for example by treating it as a factor.

Hence

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=iris[1], y = iris[2])) + geom_point(aes(shape=as.factor(iris[5])))
```

generates your errors but

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=iris[,1], y = iris[,2])) + geom_point(aes(shape=as.factor(iris[,5])))
```

and

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width )) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=as.factor(Species)))
```

do not.
Note that by default ggplot is limited to 6 shapes (though you can override) so as.factor() will create other issues if you apply it to othr variables.

So as the error message indicates, switch from using a data frame to a different data type.

Comment: That's  the second issue  issue.  The first part error message is "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame."   SO I'll agree with you halfway and say he should say as.factor().

Comment: Updated to incorporate your suggestion, I don't think this is actually a duplicate because of the data.frame issue.

Comment: Hm, fair. It plots anyway until it needs a discrete scale, but it does throw warnings (or messages, at least; I'm not sure if they're technically warnings).